# Own defined color and pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, errors, color

My codes are follows:

```
% Using spot colors with xcolor and pstricks.
% process with:
% $ latex xcpst
% $ dvips -h tex.pro -h xcolor.pro -h spot.pro filename.dvi
\begin{filecontents*}{PANTONE300C.pro}
% spot.pro
TeXDict begin
/SpotsCMYK [1 0.62 0.07 0] def
/Pantone300CSpot (Pantone300C) def
/Pantone300CDef SpotsCMYK aload pop Pantone300CSpot
findcmykcustomcolor def
/XC@Pantone300C{ Pantone300CDef 1.0 setcustomcolor}XCdef
/XC@Pantone300C100{ Pantone300CDef 1.0 setcustomcolor}XCdef
/XC@Pantone300C80{ Pantone300CDef 0.8 setcustomcolor}XCdef
/XC@Pantone300C60{ Pantone300CDef 0.6 setcustomcolor}XCdef
/XC@Pantone300C40{ Pantone300CDef 0.4 setcustomcolor}XCdef
/XC@Pantone300C20{ Pantone300CDef 0.2 setcustomcolor}XCdef
/XC@Pantone300C0{ Pantone300CDef 0 setcustomcolor}XCdef

/XC@Pantone300C9{ Pantone300CDef 0.09 setcustomcolor}XCdef
/XC@Pantone300C10{ Pantone300CDef 0.10 setcustomcolor}XCdef
/XC@Pantone300C12{ Pantone300CDef 0.12 setcustomcolor}XCdef
/XC@Pantone300C15{ Pantone300CDef 0.15 setcustomcolor}XCdef
/XC@Pantone300C30{ Pantone300CDef 0.30 setcustomcolor}XCdef
/XC@Pantone300C18{ Pantone300CDef 0.18 setcustomcolor}XCdef
/XC@Pantone300C50{ Pantone300CDef 0.50 setcustomcolor}XCdef
/XC@Pantone300C8{ Pantone300CDef 0.08 setcustomcolor}XCdef
end
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[prologue]{xcolor}%
\RequirePackage[dvips]{pstcol}%
\RequirePackage{pst-plot}%
\RequirePackage{pstricks,pst-xkey}%
\input pst-grad%
\input colordvi%%

\usepackage{pgfplots}%

\definecolor{Pantone300C}{cmyk}{1 0 0 0}
\colorlet{Pantone300C100}{Pantone300C}
\colorlet{Pantone300C80}{Pantone300C!10}
\colorlet{Pantone300C60}{Pantone300C!60}
\colorlet{Pantone300C40}{Pantone300C!40}
\colorlet{Pantone300C20}{Pantone300C!20}
\colorlet{Pantone300C10}{Pantone300C!10}%%10 percent

\begin{document}

\colorbox{Pantone300C}{\vbox to 5pc{\hbox to 10pc{\hfill}\vfill}}

\vspace{2pc}

\colorbox{Pantone300C80}{\vbox to 5pc{\hbox to 10pc{\hfill}\vfill}}

\vspace{2pc}

\psframebox[linewidth=0pt,linecolor=white,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Pantone300C80]
{\vbox
to 5pc{\vfill\hbox to 5pc{\hfill}\vfill}}

\newpage

\psframebox[linewidth=0pt,linecolor=white,fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=Pantone300C,gradend=white,gradmidpoint=-.90,framearc=0]{\hbox to 192mm{\vbox to 250mm{}}}

\newpage

\definecolor{gradbeginc}{cmyk}{0, .10, .20, 0.15}
\definecolor{gradendc}{cmyk}{0, 0, .10, 0}

\psset{linestyle=none,fillstyle=gradient,gradlines=60,
  gradbegin=gradendc,gradend=gradbeginc,
  gradmidpoint=0,gradangle=90}
\psframe(0,0)(13,-22)

Test
\end{document}
```

without the tag `\usepackage{pgfplots}` above said codes are working fine and the PDF generated successfully, but if I use the `pgfplots` then PDF not generated, can anyone suggest how can I fix this? Note that I should use the `pgfplots` package.

I am using `dvips` for generating the PS file by using the command:

```
dvips -Ppdf -h tex.pro -h xcolor.pro -h PANTONE300C.pro test.dvi
```

and then `PS2PDF` for generating the PDF file

Comment: Even without `pgfplots` the output is not what you want. Both gradients are being output in RGB. Would you consider moving to an entire `tikz`/`pgf` solution and using `pdflatex` instead of `latex`?

Comment: Hmm. Except `colorspace` (for spot colours) no longer works with the latest updates to `tikz`.

Comment: Actually a bigger problem is that `pgf` along with `pgf-cmykshadings` does not support spot colours anyway. So although you can get your CMYK gradient working, there's no option for the spot colour gradient. Maybe I could fix this.

Comment: @DavidPurton Many thanks for your great response, please let me know once it get fix....

Comment: Don't hold your breath on getting spot colour gradients with `pgf`. It could be quite hard to implement.

Comment: @DavidPurton Yes, I already understood the complexity and how complex it is!! as of now, I already proceeded with the Tricks in PDF directly..